# Python xlrd library error No such file or directory

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I'm getting this error when I try to run my program:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/PythonProgram/sample.xls'
```

I tried replacing the / slash with \, but to no avail. Assertions don't work either, and I'm positive that both the name and file directory is correct. Also, changing it to sample.xlsx doesn't work.

Here's the code:

```
import xlrd
import os.path
data_folder = "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/PythonProgram/"
file_name = "sample.xls"
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(data_folder, file_name))
```

Comment: How are you _positive_ the paths are correct if the _OS_ disagrees with you?  Python is reporting an error being forwarded up from the system API.  Are you on a domain?  Does `os.listdir(data_folder)` work?

Comment: @Jasper - forward slashes are fine in python on Windows.  That would not be the cause of trouble.

Comment: It was a stupid error. The file I had was basically a shortcut to the actually file in another directory.